# How to display a pandas Series in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable target_test (for machine learning) and I'd like to display just one element of target_test.

`type(target_test)` print the following statement on the terminal :

*`class 'pandas.core.series.Series'`*

If I do `print(target_test)` then I get the entire 2 vectors that are displayed.

But I'd like to print just the second element of the first column for example.

So do you have an idea how I could do that ?

I convert target_test to frame or to xarray but it didn't change the error I get.

When I write something like : `print(targets_test[0][0])`

I got the following output :

*`TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`*

Comment: `target_test.iloc[1]`?

Comment: Think about a pandas series as a dictionnary. The first columns are the keys and the second the values. Therefore `targets_test[0]` should do the trick. (or `targets_test.iloc[0]` if you have a custom index).

Comment: that's working , thank you very much :D , It gaves me the same result that " targets_test.values[i] " answered by tif

Comment: oups I just saw your comment ysearka , I tried several times targets_test[0] it didn't work but targets_test.iloc[i] and targets_test.values[i] are working for the second column , and targets_test.keys()[i] is working for the first column :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first column, you can use `targets_test.keys()[i]`, for the second one `targets_test.values[i]` where i is the row starting from 0.

Answer (score 1):

the first vector is the index, second one is the the value.
to print the first value use `target_test[0]`

See [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for more information.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s=pd.Series({'a':12.3,'b':34.5,'c':45.6})
>>> s
a    12.3
b    34.5
c    45.6
dtype: float64
>>>
>>> s[0]
12.3
>>> s.iloc[0]
12.3
```